# How to modify the configuration of Kafka to process large amount of data

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using kafka_2.10-0.10.0.1. I have two questions:
- I want to know how I can modify the default configuration of Kafka to process large amount of data with good performance.
- Is it possible to configure Kafka to process the records in memory without storing in disk? 
thank you

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to configure Kafka to process the records in memory without storing in disk?

No. Kafka is all about storing records reliably on disk, and then reading them back quickly off of disk. In fact, [its documentation says](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/):

> As a result of taking storage seriously and allowing the clients to control their read position, you can think of Kafka as a kind of special purpose distributed filesystem dedicated to high-performance, low-latency commit log storage, replication, and propagation.

You can read more about its design here: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#design. The implementation section is also quite interesting: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#implementation.

That said, Kafka is also all about processing large amounts of data with good performance. In 2014 it could handle 2 million writes per second on three cheap instances: https://engineering.linkedin.com/kafka/benchmarking-apache-kafka-2-million-writes-second-three-cheap-machines. More links about performance:

- https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/deployment.html
- https://www.confluent.io/blog/optimizing-apache-kafka-deployment/
- https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/80813/kafka-best-practices-1.html
- https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/kafka/latest/topics/kafka_performance.html

Comment: thank you, my question is: Kafka uses key-value pairs in the configuration files with default values. Can I modify some default values in order to get better performance and to support larger amounts of data?

Comment: No, I've never really tweaked Kafka. As it says in that blog post about performance: "I think the real test of a system is not how it performs when perfectly tuned, but rather how it performs "off the shelf". This is particularly true for systems that run in a multi-tenant setup with dozens or hundreds of use cases where tuning for each use case would be not only impractical but impossible. As a result, I have pretty much stuck with default settings"

Comment: Here is the configuration for that blog: https://gist.github.com/jkreps/c7ddb4041ef62a900e6c#file-server-config-properties

Comment: Basically if you want top performance you want your logs to be on fast SSDs, on fast instances with fast networking. You can even use multiple drives to get more throughput: https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/80813/kafka-best-practices-1.html. It's not very configuration-oriented.